# How do I add a ml.linalg.Vector field to a Spark StructType?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-mllib

This is the code:

```
val originalSchema: StructType = ...
val newSchema: StructType = originalSchema
    .add(StructField("featureVector", ???, false))
```

NOTE: I need a `ml.linalg.Vector` and not a `mllib.linalg.Vector`. My "featureVector" will be the input to a MLlib classifier and that's the only type supported.